# apply curves filter when converting image sequence to video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an image sequence to a video with the following command:

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -vf curves=m='0/0 0.5/0.8 1/1' -i CAPTURETEMP\captureImg_%05d.png RECORDINGS\recording.mp4`

but ffmpeg throws me
"[AVFormatContext @ 000001ed798d6a40] Unable to choose an output format for '0.5/0.8'; use a standard extension for the filename or specify the format manually." no matter where i put the "-vf curves..." part.

running it without like
`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i CAPTURETEMP\captureImg_%05d.png RECORDINGS\recording.mp4`
works fine.

so far i could only find examples for -vf without relation to other parameters... I'm very new to ffmpeg :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate curve values with a comma, not a space.
You should also place the input before the filter.

Example below:

```
ffmpeg -i img%%5d.png -vf curves=m='0/0,0.5/0.8,1/1' -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 output.mp4
```

You can omit `-pix_fmt` if you are happy with yuv444.